# Manejo de topónimos extranjeros en títulos

Tags: extranjerismos, topónimos

¿Cómo deben manejarse los nombres de ciudades o países extranjeros en títulos de canciones o de medios de comunicación que tienen equivalente en español? Por ejemplo, lo habitual es oír del *New York Times*, del *Folha de Sao Paulo* (En el Río de la plata es San Pablo), de *France Football*, la *Deustche Welle* o incluso de la *BBC*, aunque en el último caso, en Wikipedia se menciona la Corporación de Radiodifusión Británica. ¿En estos casos no es necesario traducir la referencia de la ciudad o del país al español?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Este tema se trata en el [capítulo 3.2.2](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=fnRLvBRzvjkpodJy) de la *Ortografía 2010* de la RAE, titulado "Trasferencia, traducción e hipanización de topónimos":

> [...] podría entenderse por traducción de un topónimo su hispanización (*París*, por *Paris*) o su sustitución por el exónimo tradicional (*Birmania*, en lugar de *Myanmar*); solo cabría hablar de traducción en sentido estricto en casos como *la Selva Negra*, por *Schwarzwald* donde el nombre español constituye la traducción exacta de los elementos que componen el término alemán. Los topónimos que aluden en su denominación a un referente geográfico genérico que encuentra correspondencia en la realidad son más proclives a la traducción literal: así, *Costa Azul* resulta apropiado en lugar de la expresión francesa *Côte d'Azur*, frente a *Reinas*, solución extraña en referencia al distrito de Nueva York llamado *Queens*.

Continúa la *Ortografía* hablando de sustantivos referentes a accidentes geográficos: *bahía de Chesapeake*, *Costa de Marfil*, comentando que cuanto mayor es la magnitud del referente geográfico del topónimo, mayor es la frecuencia de uso de este, que tiende a adoptar y fijar una forma española. En todo caso, dice que el uso actual revela una clara predilección por la transferencia de la forma original, sobre todo cuando no existía una denominación española tradicional: *Aix-en-Provence*, *Montpellier*, *Plymouth*... incluso para términos "poco amigables" para los españoles, aunque nos resulten poco familiares: *Daikondi*, provincia afgana, *Vestmannaeyjar*, islas al sur de Islandia. Algunas incluso han quedado relegadas al olvido, como *Mastrique*, exónimo español desusado para *Maastricht*.

> Ahora bien, siempre que exista un exónimo tradicional asentado que siga vigente, esto es, que siga siendo mayoritariamente empleado por los hispanohablantes, se recomienda conservarlo [...]. No constituyen una excepción los exónimos que forman parte del nombre de equipos deportivos radicados en el lugar al que alude el topónimo: *Estrella Roja de Belgrado, Inter de Milán, Steaua de Bucarest, Juventus de Turín*. Pese a que, en los últimos años, los medios de comunicación tienden a mantener la forma original en estas denominaciones, se recomienda emplear, cuando exista, la forma tradicional española.

Este último párrafo responde al ejemplo que comentas del *Folha de São Paulo*, aunque precisamente en este caso *São Paulo* es un topónimo aceptado en español, aunque también se usa *San Pablo*. Para el resto de casos que comentas, en realidad son casos distintos, dado que se trata de topónimos integrados en marcas registradas, y en este caso hay que respetar la denominación de dicha marca. Por tanto, hay que decir *New York Times*. Para el caso de nombres de corporaciones sí se admite la traducción, como el caso de la BBC, aunque en este caso la corporación sea más conocida por sus siglas (seguramente nadie sepa qué significan en japonés las siglas de la NHK, pero muchos sabrán que es como se llama una cadena de televisión de allí). En el caso de la *Deutsche Welle* no parece haber una traducción asentada, así que se usa el término original (y además, si dices "Onda alemana" se puede prestar a confusión).